# Android Insets cropping Toolbar

Tags: android, windowinsets

I need to make my app respond to the onscreen keyboard. So before API 30 I was just using

```
requireActivity().window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

but since this is deprecated now, I tried to use the solution the documentation states by adjusting the insets.
At first it didn't seem to recognize the statusbar moving the view (including the toolbar) up. But I eventually (almost) managed it by writing this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    requireActivity().window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
    requireActivity().window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, windowInsets ->
        val imeHeight = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime())
        val statusBarsHeight = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())

        v.setPadding( /*left  */ imeHeight.left,       // = 0
                      /*top   */ statusBarsHeight.top, // = 66
                      /*right */ imeHeight.right,      // = 0
                      /*bottom*/ imeHeight.bottom)     // = 0
        WindowInsets.Builder()
            .setInsets(0, imeHeight)
            .build()
    }
}
```

The spacing seems to work. The Toolbar is not moving up any longer. However, it seems the padding I applied is cropping it instead. In the following picture you can see the normal (left) and the new (right) layout. The padding seems to overpaint the toolbar.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]